# Getting different results when using shell operators -ne and !=

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, ubuntu, wsl-2

I wrote the below shell script, when using `-ne` it gives the result **Synced** but also with a warning message `: integer expression expected`.
When I use `!=` it gives **NotSynced**...
Is PowerShell's datetime different than Ubuntu's datetime?! (Am I comparing integers with strings!?)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

WinTime=$(powershell.exe "& {get-date -UFormat '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'}")
WSLTime=$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

echo "$WinTime"
echo "$WSLTime"

if [ "$WinTime" != "$WSLTime" ]; then
    echo "  Windows: $WinTime"
    echo "  WSL:    $WSLTime"
    echo "NotSynced"
else
    echo "Synced"
fi
```

**Using `!=`**:
[image]
**Using `-ne`**:
[image]

Comment: It can't be integer (-ne).  Wouldn't the seconds be different sometimes?

Comment: I run it more than 10 times, datetimes look exactly the same...

Comment: Added the pictures

Comment: Comparing '2023/02/07 18:40:16' with -ne makes no sense because it's not an integer.

Comment: `-ne` is used to compare integers; `!=` is used to compare strings; `2023/02/07 18:41:29` is a string so you should be using `!=` as the comparison operator; now, if you were to generate the date/time stamps as 'seconds since eopoch' (`%s` => an integer) *then* you could use `-ne` as the comparion operator

Comment: @markp-fuso Thanks, I used that, but that doesn't give the desired output... just wonder why it echoes `NotSynced`!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question's original issue was the difference between `-ne` and `!=`; this was addressed in comments.

Once OP switched to using `!=` this allowed the second issue to bubble to the top ... the `!=` was evaulating as 'true' when the two strings appeared to be the same.

This answer addresses the second issue ...

---

I'm running `bash` in a `cygwin` environment (ie, under windows so I have access to `powershell.exe`).

Running OP's code I also get the same results:

```
Windows: 2023/02/07 09:32:47
WSL:     2023/02/07 09:32:47
NotSynced
```

If we take a look at the actual contents of these 2 variables we see:

```
$ echo "$WinTime" | od -c
0000000   2   0   2   3   /   0   2   /   0   7       0   9   :   3   2
0000020   :   4   7  \r  \n
0000025

$ echo "$WSLTime" | od -c
0000000   2   0   2   3   /   0   2   /   0   7       0   9   :   3   2
0000020   :   4   7  \n
0000024
```

Notice that `$WinTime` includes a trailing `\r` (windows/dos line ending) which is the result of running the Windows binary `powershell.exe`.  This extra `\r` is causing the conditional to evaluate as 'true' and thus print  `NotSynced`.

OP will want to remove the trailing `\r`.

I don't know enough about `powershell` to know if it has an option to disable the `\r` so I'll let `tr` remove the `\r`:

```
WinTime=$(powershell.exe "& {get-date -UFormat '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'}" | tr -d '\r')
```

We can see the `\r` no longer exists:

```
$ echo "$WinTime" | od -c
0000000   2   0   2   3   /   0   2   /   0   7       0   9   :   3   6
0000020   :   2   2  \n
0000024
```

And now the conditional evaluates as 'false' and prints `Synced`.

**NOTE:** the script could still report `NotSynced` in the scenario where the two time capture commands run just before/after a change in seconds

Comment: I can confirm the behavior in wsl.  I tried `powershell "(get-date) -replace '\r'"`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this wasn't the question originally asked.

Comment: @js2010 fair point; I've updated the answer to address the perceived disconnect between question and answer